# Two stage sampling method for my research in high schools

Tags: sampling

My research will be in high schools. Sample size will be over 300 and I have to choose them among 13 schools. Total number of students is over 3000 and when I think about sampling method, two stage sampling method with probability proportional to size is suitable. First I will choose 4 cluster and then choose 300 participants. But problem is the number of students is different between clusters. Some have few student eg 80 and some have many eg over 500. So, if I will choose 80 students per school, I don't need to do second stage for schools with few student? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What are your logistic and budget constraints? In schools, it is often difficult to pull some students out of the classroom and leave others in, so it may be easier, if not the only thing possible, to do whatever you are planning to do, with the whole class. As far as budgets are concerned, you may have costs at the school level, either the actual costs (interviewer travel) or "moral" (communicating with the school administration to get permissions, etc.). This may need to be incorporated into your design.

Comment: Usually the better designs, in terms of power and precision, are those with more clusters, so you may want to consider trying all 13 schools with fewer students per school if possible (see the previous comment). With 4 schools sampled, you will only have 4 degrees of freedom for your analyses, and that ain't much.